# proper way to configure a project in eclipse for eSWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, eclipse-rcp

can someone direct me on how to configure a project in eclipse so that i can utilise eSWT.
Just by manually adding `eswt-converged.jar` gives me build/pre verification errors.

I downloaded [this](http://www.findthatzipfile.com/search-42043261-hZIP/winrar-winzip-download-ercp-1.3-wm6std-20090806.zip.htm) and utilised the jar from the folder and copied it to my project folder and added it to the build path.But it shows me something like

[image]

Please help.

**EDIT**
i did what Neil said and i am getting this now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see that in the [link you provided](http://www.findthatzipfile.com/search-42043261-hZIP/winrar-winzip-download-ercp-1.3-wm6std-20090806.zip.htm), there are a number of other jars that I don't see included in your project.  If I had to take a guess, your jar is heavily dependent on these jars which aren't there, so all the classes that it uses which are defined in these jars simply aren't there.

Though, without further information on the nature of the problem, it's difficult to determine anything else I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi Neil,problem is that even i cannot understand the nature of the problem.It's so confusing.I will try to include those jars too,but now i was trying to download the eSWT source and throw it into my `src` lol.

Comment: @Nezam What types of problems do you see listed in the "Problems" tab in eclipse?  If you don't see it, you can go to Windows -> Show view -> Other and find "Problems".

Comment: i'll show that in the edit once i am done with what you said.Inshallah

Comment: man.. now i get errors on all those jars which i imported from the link.All red.Most of them show `preverification errors`

Comment: @Nezam [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161078/error-preverifying-class-java-eclipse-blackberry).  You may have a problem with the version of your java virtual machine.  What version(s) of the java virtual machine do you have installed on your computer?

Comment: i don't know i havent installed anything other than what was already there by default.Tell me how to find which JVMs are installed.

Comment: @Nezam The java virtual machine is normally saved in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk 1.6 (where 1.6 would be your version).  It may also be jre instead of jdk also.

Comment: you're right i had:
`C:\jdk1.3.0_05`
`jdk1.7.0_09`
`jre6`
`jre7`

I changed the alternate jre to 1.3 so now the red marks are gone from the items but the preverifying errors are still there.